# Zxing Lib is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, zxing, barcode-scanner

Friends I m using zxing 2.2 lib for barcode scanning.. I see the different tutorials for that.
Firstly when I include capture activity lib in eclips. it shows error in it.. I find the solution. and add a core.jar file. error removes successfully. but when I make capture activity as library. it again shows error . which I remove by converting switch statement into if else..
now there is no error in library. I include it in my project.. and use the code for barcode scanning.. but its not open even camera and close my app..

// here is my Main Activity code...

```
       package com.bluehorn.diamondfusion;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;

public class FusionMain extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener  {

        Button btnScan;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnScan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
        btnScan.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v== btnScan){
          Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
      intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        }

        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
               if (requestCode == 0) {
              if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                  String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                  // Handle successful scan
                   AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FusionMain.this)
                   .create();
                     alert.setTitle("BarCode Result");
                     alert.setMessage(contents+"    \n        "+format);
                     alert.show();
                    }
                  else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                       AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FusionMain.this)
                        .create();
                     alert.setTitle("BarCode Result");
                     alert.setMessage("error  ,,,");
                     alert.show();
                  }

               }
            }
    }
```

// and this is my android manefist file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bluehorn.diamondfusion"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bluehorn.diamondfusion.FusionMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

// LogCat ...

```
07-19 04:49:37.030: D/dalvikvm(3423): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 51% free 2674K/5379K, external 1031K/1038K, paused 30ms
07-19 04:49:37.060: D/dalvikvm(3423): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 3K, 51% free 2676K/5379K, external 1241K/1298K, paused 10ms
07-19 04:49:41.490: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(3423): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1322 (ISSUE_NUMBER) in Lcom/google/zxing/ResultMetadataType;
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0017
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x0019-0025 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.<clinit> ()V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: I/dalvikvm(3423): Could not find method com.google.zxing.ResultPoint.getX, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.drawLine
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4441: Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;.getX ()F
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x0007-0020 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.drawLine (Landroid/graphics/Canvas;Landroid/graphics/Paint;Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;F)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: I/dalvikvm(3423): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getResultPoints, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.drawResultPoints
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4437: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getResultPoints ()[Lcom/google/zxing/ResultPoint;
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0003
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x0006-0070 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.drawResultPoints (Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;FLcom/google/zxing/Result;)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: I/dalvikvm(3423): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.toString, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecodeExternally
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4440: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x00c9
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x00cc-0169 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.handleDecodeExternally (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/result/ResultHandler;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x0187-01a5 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.handleDecodeExternally (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/result/ResultHandler;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: I/dalvikvm(3423): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getBarcodeFormat, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecodeInternally
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4434: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getBarcodeFormat ()Lcom/google/zxing/BarcodeFormat;
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x004a
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x004d-01b3 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.handleDecodeInternally (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/result/ResultHandler;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x01bb-022a in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.handleDecodeInternally (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/result/ResultHandler;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: I/dalvikvm(3423): Could not find method com.google.zxing.Result.getText, referenced from method com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.handleDecode
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 4438: Lcom/google/zxing/Result;.getText ()Ljava/lang/String;
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x006f
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: dead code 0x0072-0091 in Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;.handleDecode (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;F)V
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/zxing/Result;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity;)
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/AndroidRuntime(3423): Shutting down VM
07-19 04:49:44.880: W/dalvikvm(3423): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f8c4f0)
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/AndroidRuntime(3423): procName from cmdline: com.bluehorn.diamondfusion
07-19 04:49:44.880: E/AndroidRuntime(3423): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.bluehorn.diamondfusion
07-19 04:49:44.880: D/AndroidRuntime(3423): file written successfully with content: com.bluehorn.diamondfusion StringBuffer : ;com.bluehorn.diamondfusion
07-19 04:49:44.890: I/Process(3423): Sending signal. PID: 3423 SIG: 9
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:97)
07-19 04:49:44.890: E/AndroidRuntime(3423):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: post your logcat please..

Comment: Read the FAQ. SO does not have a paid thingy. And clean up your question, too much empty space. Waste of scroll.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is a problem with the built path. Right click on your project, Click on project >properties>build path. Click on order and export tab then check on all the library files. Let me know if it worked

Comment: Please put the logcat details in a blockquote. it is very difficult to read

Comment: Check Logcate detail ... i have improve my question with Log cat detail

Comment: Right click on your project, Click on project >properties>build path. Click on order and export tab click on yourprojectname/src and click on down. And be sure to let me know if it works

Comment: Brother Let me know... when we add capture activity as library... what should be the target for it... i select 4.2.2.. i think,,, this may be a reason for failure.. ??

Comment: Hi,i have implemented zxing as well let me know the steps you followed in importing the zxing library

Comment: brother ... i download zxing 2.2 from link which is every where available..
(1) in eclipse i include the android folder which is in that zxing 2.2 folder
(2) it becomes capture activity when included..
(3) that time.. there was many errors which was due to core.jar file
(4) I Search Core.jar file from internet and include in capture activity
(5) Errors Removed. but when i make it as library . then it again gives me some error on switch statements . i found the solution and convert all switch statements into if/else. and save change .. clean the project 
(6) then i add this lib into my project

Comment: My project code . android manefest file code. and log cat detail is in question... you can see. plz help me... i m in a great hurry  :(

Comment: If you are in a hurry I would recommend using zbar till this problem gets solved.Its much easier to integrate wont take more than 30 minutes.heres something for reference.  https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner